# Take a sreen shot without making a window dissapear when clicking the keys to take the shot

Tags: 18.04, screen

Ubuntu 18.4. I am having trouble connecting to our VPN and wanted to post on a forum with a picture of the VPN window attempting to connect. For this I had to take a photo with my phone as opposed to a screen shot:
[image]

When I press shift + print screen, that window in the upper right vanishes since it's no longer in focus.

I installed flames app but the same thing happens when activating a screen shot, since the window is not active, it disappears.

How can I take a screen shot without the small popup window disappearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch the GNOME screenshot tool from the applications menu and configure a delay to make a screenshot after - say - 10 seconds. Then click the button to do the screenshot (the screenshot tool window will disappear) and start connecting via your VPN. After 10 seconds from your click of the "Screenshot" button the screenshot will be taken automatically, the screenshot tool window will re-appear and you can save your screenshot.